# amazon ec2 No route to host error suddenly, public IP ping fails with general error

Tags: amazon-ec2

amazon EC2 instance is running perfectly fine. But when trying to connect using putty or via browser its not pinging. My security group is set correctly because this issue happened when everything was working fine, its a live system.

when I try to ping my elastic IP it returns general failure, but everything seems to be fine in EC2 management console. Not sure where to start trouble shoot.

Comment: What did Amazon Support say about this?

Comment: I would release the EIP and re-associate

Comment: @silviud your solution worked, but still trying to recover lost items, not sure how to mark this question as answered. your help is really timely and want to thank you. do you have any idea why suddenly this happens

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer?
Mee too getting the same error - `ssh: connect to host xx.xx.245.37 port xxxx: No route to host`!

Can you elaborate what exactly you did?
@SquaplRecipes and @silviud